# Is it possible to run multiple Karate instances concurrently using the same JVM?

Tags: karate

I am executing multiple Runners concurrently. Those Runners use @SpringBootTest to start multiple Spring Boot Applications (one for each Runner). So far, so good. The applications start without any issues using different spring profiles.

I would like to run different feature files on each Runner, using different karate-config-env.js files. Is it possible? I took a look at the Runner and Builder class of Karate and everything seems static.

In other words, is Karate multi-thread safe?

I created two Runners and executed them in parallel (configured JUnit to do that). Each Runner uses a different spring profile.

Answer (score 0):

Karate is designed to be able to use 2 `Runner`s in parallel. The class that holds all the work is the [`Suite`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/v1.3.1/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/Suite.java) - and the `Runner.Builder` eventually just constructs a `Suite`.

That said, a second opinion and code-contributions (if needed) are most welcome.

Comment: Just to confirm that it works. I was able to use 10 Runners in parallel.